# Custom ripple effect in android for lower version

Tags: android

How can we give custom ripple effect in android? I want to override default ripple color effect. Plus I also want to support API level 15 onwards.

Comment: Why don't you use this library https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. Follow the steps of integration. It support from API 9+

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to have Ripple Effects starting API 15 onwards

1. [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)
2. [Material Ripple Layout](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)

Compile the library in the build.gradle. All the usage in the documentation. Usage example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
}
```

Comment: I'll try this for sure. Thanks though.